# Can Flink keyed process function have multiple state descriptors?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using Keyed process function to use RocksDB state backend. I want to hold two different states for the same key;

- State 1 type: ValueState[String]
- State 2 type: MapState[String, Long]

In this case, i have to create two state descriptors in the same keyed process function. Is that possible in flink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have as many state descriptors in a keyed process function as you want. Each must have a unique name (scoped to the operator/function).

See [the solution](https://github.com/apache/flink-training/blob/master/rides-and-fares/src/solution/java/org/apache/flink/training/solutions/ridesandfares/RidesAndFaresSolution.java) to the [Rides and Fares training exercise](https://github.com/apache/flink-training/tree/master/rides-and-fares) for an example.